# How do I access the Magento system config?

Tags: magento

I've just recently installed Magento 2.0.2 (I'm new to Magento) and have been following some tutorials and documentation to do it.

I've noticed that a lot of screenshots and tutorials ask to go to **System > Configuration** but when I log into my Magento admin, there is no such option (screenshot below). I tried to go into Web Setup Wizard where is asked me for a public/private access key which I generated and entered, now when I go into the Web Setup Wizard, it just shows this (screenshot 2 below).

I don't know what to do, can anyone please enlighten me?

[image: magento 2.0.2 system menu]
[image: magento 2.0.2 system config]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity, ok thanks I'll post it there

Comment: Moved to http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114195/how-do-i-access-the-magento-system-config

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2, You can access the Configuration section from `Store` >> `Configuration`

[image]